# Perform filtering of "Sede"depending on the user

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I comment on what I want to do. I want that when creating a new user and selecting any of the "locations" that it has, then only the locations that said user has selected when creating a new file are displayed. I explain step by step:

1. When opening the user view a block of "sedes" is observed.

[image]

2. Depending on the selected "sedes" of the user, when creating a new file, only the "sedes" that only that user has and not all of them are shown, as it happens to me.

[image]

I attach the view of "File.jsp" that contains the following of "sede":

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Sede</span> <select ng-model="expediente.sede" ng-options="sede as sede.nombre for sede in sedes track by sede.id" class="form-control" ng-disabled="creado" required></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi can you explain more on your code ? how the other sedes are populated ? And what do you mean by `creating a new file..` ?

Answer (score 0):

I make a brief summary. I create a user who can assign a series of locations. What I want to do is that when I create a file with this user in the "Headquarters" field, I only want the headquarters that said user has to appear, for example, if the user has the headquarters of Seville and Córdoba, when creating the file that It only allows me to select Seville or Córdoba in the drop-down list and not all the available venues as seen in the second image. To see all the venues I have the following code: **ng-model="expediente.sede" ng-options="sede as sede.nombre for sede in sedes track by sede.id"**, but I only want to show me the selected venues in the user's view . I suppose that the problem is in the action of the "ng-options". The following code is from the user view where it shows all the "sedes":
[image]

How could I filter only the locations that the user has?